# Trouble getting value from function to new variable

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why the functions return is not being grabbed by “var”.  I am using a select object to pass the parameter:

```
<select name="BILLTOSTATE" onchange="setBTS(this) >
<option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
<option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
ETC….
```

Function I would like to receive that value:

```
function setBTS(val){
var lv_bts = val.value;
return lv_bts;
}
```

And lastly the VAR I would like to set from setBTS function:

```
var lv_bts = setBTS();
```

Also I don’t know if it matters, but the new VAR lv_bts is located inside another function. Thanks.  Sorry for this question.  I'm new to this and I’m sure the answer is easy and in my face!

Comment: What are you talking about? You aren't even passing a parameter.

Comment: Well I am, I just didn't show that. Thought it would have been assumed. I'll be more direct in future post

Comment: well you call a function and do not pass anything to it and you try to read the attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function setBTS takes a parameter as an argument, when you call it you would also need to supply that parameter in order to receive it back.

Think of it like this:

```
function myFunction(necessaryArgumentForFunction) {
    let internalVariable = necessaryArgumentForFunction.value;
    return internalVariable;
}
let variable = { value: 'some value' };
cont lv_bts = myFunction(variable);
console.log(lv_bts);
```

## EDIT - (same day)

*Add some details on question formatting in relation to thread below*

- When you are setting up a question either concisely explain anything you aren't showing or add code snippets.

  - #### For Example:

    This method is being called by an event handler which is passing its state (this/event) in as an argument.
  - #### Or:

    `let ele = document.getElementById('myEle');
    ele.onChange = setBTS;`
- Also a good idea to add any failed strategies you have attempted (with results) to save you and people trying to help some time
- I personally also like to include any technologies I'm using that may be relevant with versions (eg `Node v8.1.4, npm v5.3.0`) sometimes it helps surface known issues or idiosyncracies that might not be immediately apparent if you aren't as familiar with the library.

Anyway, I hope that helps :D. Have a good one.

Comment: Thanks D Lowther, appreciate the answer.  Hey how come I keep getting negative hits on my questions?  Am I saying something wrong?

Comment: I'm not certain, your question seemed pretty straightforward and you noted that it was a basic level one in your last sentence.

Comment: @LeeAlexander: Your question doesn't make sense.  What does `Is it because there is already a value in the () from the SELECT onchange(this)` mean?

Comment: @SLaks brings a valid point, The first sentence before your code does indicate that there is more here code wise that we aren't seeing that could be causing the problem. I'm going to edit my answer to add some question formatting tips :)

Comment: I was saying that I have a SELECT ele that is passing (this) to that function.  I didn't want to waste anyone's time reading things that they would assume I'm doing.  It clearly says "onchange(this)" so I must be using something to send that val.  But like I said, I will be more specific in the future.

Comment: Ok fair enough, I will add more details on other questions

Answer (score 0):

`setBTS` is expecting an argument; you aren't passing one.

Answer (score 0):

`setBTS(val)` is expecting a parameter, which is not passed when you are calling the function, Hence val.value will be undefined since `val` is undefined